# Free shipping for specific categories

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am looking at creating a shopping cart rule so that if an item is added to the basket, free shipping is applied. I have tried a few options but it does not seem to work. I have managed to get the code to work and it applies the free shipping and its displayed on the checkout.

However when I remove my coupon code the shipping amount changes. I have checked the shipping matrix, but it does not seem to be this that is causing the issue. Any rough ideas, of what could be causing it?

Comment: Please note that Magento coupon free shipping actually discounts the items rather than the shipping amount

Answer (score 1):

Just goto **Action** tab of Shipping Cart rules.

then go ***Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)***

and create a condition  on **Category**

And then **Free Shipping**=  *`For matching items only`*.

It will work